# Remove suffix: from properties and xmlns: from root

Tags: .net, wcf

I just want a plain xml as below

Blockquote

```
<error>
<message>Attempted to divide by zero.</message>
<status>500</status>

</error>
```

but i am getting some thing as below

```
<error xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mynamespace.Service.Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:message>Attempted to divide by zero.</a:message>
<a:status>500</a:status>
</error>
```

what can i do to remove xmlns: and a:

my development is like
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/97ddb118-fdfd-4651-9e61-4d822861325f

```
protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
{
    this.serializer.WriteObject(writer, this.faultDetails);
 }
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the namespace? What business or technical purpose would that serve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom serializer. I wonder why you want to do it. Rather writing custom serializer, use regex on client side to remove the string.

Comment: At least i want get rid off the  a:

Comment: a: is namespace prefix. You see the declaration xmlns:a="blah blah". Use regex to replace <Sometext: with <.